# How semaphore value is checked using '==' operator?

Tags: semaphore, os161

A semaphore is declared and created like this --

```
static struct semaphore *done;
done = sem_create("done",0); // semaphore value initialized to zero
```

Now what happens when,

```
if(done==NULL)
{
     //Something done here...
}
```

the if condition is executed above ? since done was set to 0 do the statements inside the if block get executed ?

Comment: What library are you using for this particular semaphore?

Comment: Written in c for os161

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`done` is a pointer to semaphore, and the condition `done==NULL` checks whether the creation of a new semaphore succeeded, in which case `done` will hold the address of the new semaphore, or failed, in which case `done` will hold `NULL`.

In short, this condition does not check the state of the semaphore, but if it was created at all.

Answer (score 1):

I am answering this question with respect to OS161 implementations.
done is a pointer to semaphore and it would be NULL only when the sem_create does not create the semaphore due to memory not available or other memory constraints.

The 0 value that is passed as a parameter to a function which initializes the initial count of semaphore to be 0. The count can be accessed as done->count and then a particular code can be executed depending on the count value.

While coding for OS161 I solved a few synch problems using semaphores, you could check them out at the link given below:

https://github.com/prathammalik/OS161/tree/master/kern/synchprobs